# Vue.js : How to iterate with v-for into a dynamic array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I want to display multiples html tables of tools (1 table = 1 tool's categorie / 1 tr = 1 tool).

```
data() {
    return {
      cats: '',
      tools: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getToolCats() {
      var rez = getToolCats();
      rez.then(data => this.receiveCats(data) ) 
    },
    receiveCats(_cats){
      this.cats = _cats;
      _cats.forEach(cat => {
        getToolsByCat(cat.href).then(data => this.tools[cat.href] = data);
      });
      console.log(this.tools);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getToolCats();
  },
```

cats (ie categories) is an array populated with an API call. Then for each cat, an API Call give me a tool list of that cat, that I place into the tools array (this.tools[cat.href] = data).

Here is the display code :

```
<div v-for="cat in cats" :key="cat.href" class="tbox col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    ....
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr v-for="tool in tools[cat.href]" :key="tool.href">
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    ....
</div>
```

If i'm using a single var to store lthe tool list, all is OK. But while I don't know how many cats I'm going to have, I can't create a car for each category.

I think the problem could be there :

- Using an array in v-for with a key not defined at mounted state :

> v-for="tool in tools[cat.href]

I'll appreciate any help !

Comment: `<table class="table table-hover" v-if="tools[cat.href].length">`

Comment: Thank you connexo, but tools[cat.href] doesn't exists when trying to evaluate lenght : TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: `<table class="table table-hover" v-if="tools && tools.length && tools[cat.href].length">`

Comment: No undefined anymore, but no table displayed  :-)

Comment: `tools[cat.href]` will not be observed by Vue, so no update to the UI if it changes. Your data structure does not fit the reactivity concept of Vue.

Comment: OK, is it a way to force the re-evaluation of tools[cat.href] while getting the response from my API call ? Or a way to add html including v-for after execution ?

Answer (score 0):

Vue [can't detect dynamic property addition](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) in `this.tools[cat.href] = data`, but it would detect the change with [`this.$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) or [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) in **`this.$set(this.tools, cat.href, data)`**:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      cats: [],
      tools: {}, // <-- make this an object (not an array)
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getToolCats();
  },
  methods: {
    getToolCats() {
      // setTimeout to simulate delayed API calls...
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.cats = [
          { href: 'https://google.com' },
          { href: 'https://microsoft.com' },
          { href: 'https://apple.com' },
          { href: 'https://amazon.com' },
        ];
        this.cats.forEach((cat, i) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            const data = { href: cat.href };
            this.$set(this.tools, cat.href, data); // <-- use this.$set for dynamic property addition
          }, i * 1000);
        })
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-if="!cats || cats.length == 0">Loading...</div>
  <div v-for="cat in cats" :key="cat.href" v-else>
    <table>
      <tr v-for="tool in tools[cat.href]" :key="tool.href">
        <td>cat.href: {{cat.href}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <pre>tools: {{tools}}</pre>
</div>
```